# Quickblox enterprise video conference

Tags: android, video, quickblox, conference

I am using Quickblox Video Conferencing sdk in Android. Using this ,On starting conference I can only join either as publisher or as Listener.
My question is can we switch user who joined as listener to publisher and vice versa,without closing already running conference ( without leaving session).

Answer (score 0):

In current realization of QuickBlox Android SDK (3.6.0) it is not possible.